# "Passed-object dummy argument must be a scalar"

Tags: fortran

I have type-bound procedures which I want to accept an array as their passed dummy argument (`getMean` and `assignEachThatInThis` below). This does not compile though. I have read Metcalf *et al.* and they do not say that the passed dummy argument must be scalar and I don't really understand why that would have to be the case anyway.

If I use the `nopass` attribute it does compile and so it does when the procedures are not type-bound ones.

Can someone, please, explain what is going on and what is and is not safe to do?

Here is my example:

```
module types
implicit none

integer, parameter :: DP = selected_real_kind(r=250,p=13)

type :: my_type1

        real(KIND=DP), dimension(:),   allocatable :: elem1    ! interest rate

    contains

        procedure :: getMean        => getMean_my_type1 

        procedure ::                   assignThatInThis_my_type1
        procedure ::                   assignEachThatInThis_my_type1
        generic   :: assignment (=) => assignThatInThis_my_type1, assignEachThatInThis_my_type1

end type my_type1

contains

subroutine assignThatInThis_my_type1(this,that)
        ! Defines the overloaded `=` operator for the 'my_type1' class
        ! this = that

   class(my_type1), intent(inout) :: this
   class(my_type1), intent(in)    :: that

   this%elem1  = that%elem1

end subroutine assignThatInThis_my_type1

subroutine assignEachThatInThis_my_type1(this,that)
        !--> this is apparently illegal, 'this' has to be a scalar :-(
        !--> in principle it could work with the 'nopass' attribute (see 'getMean_my_type1') but that won't work with the assignment operator '='

   class(my_type1), dimension(:), intent(inout) :: this
   class(my_type1), dimension(:), intent(in)    :: that

   integer :: i

   do i = 1,size(this,1)
      this(i) = that(i)
   end do

end subroutine assignEachThatInThis_my_type1


subroutine getMean_my_type1(this,that)

   class(my_type1), dimension(:), intent(inout) :: this
   class(my_type1),               intent(inout) :: that

   integer :: nTypes
   integer :: n
   integer :: j

   nTypes = size(this,1)
   n      = size(this(1)%elem1,1)    ! length of the simulation

   ! sum all elem1
   do j = 1,nTypes
      that%elem1 = that%elem1 + this(j)%elem1
   end do

   ! divide by the number of elements
   that%elem1 = that%elem1 / real(nTypes)

end subroutine getMean_my_type1


end module types


program pdatest
implicit none


end program pdatest
```

The following works, where I use the `nopass` attribute for `getMean` and don't have the assignment subroutines type-bound:

```
type :: my_type1

        real(KIND=DP), dimension(:),   allocatable :: elem1    ! interest rate

    contains

         procedure, nopass :: getMean        => getMean_my_type1

end type my_type1


interface assignment (=)
        module procedure assignEachThatInThis_my_type1, assignThatInThis_my_type1
end interface
```

Comment: Would you accept an answer "it's _this_ rule of Fortran" or are you after reasoning and details of implications, etc.?

Comment: @francescalus I would like to understand the reasoning and a suggestion how to go around it in a safe way.

Comment: I've done a mini-answer.  If there's something you think I should expand on or clarify, please request.

Answer (score 1):

To start, the passed-object dummy is required to be scalar (among other things) directly because of the rules of Fortran.  Consider F2008, C456:

> The passed-object dummy argument shall be a scalar, nonpointer, nonallocatable dummy data object with the same declared type as the type being defined; ...

With the `nopass` attribute the type-bound procedure reference has no passed-object, so this restriction does not apply.  Equally, if you make the subroutine reference not from its type binding, the restriction doesn't apply.

With the `getMean` binding, the desire is to reduce an array to a scalar, but with the assignment the wish is to have an input array and an output array of the same shape.  This latter is a case for an elemental subroutine.

Comment: Would you happen to know why the standard requires this restriction? The only reason I could think of was that perhaps each element in the array could have a different dynamic type. But if this was a problem then it would also be a problem with `nopass`. I was mainly thinking, whatever the reason is, why doesn't it apply to both cases equally, i.e. with `nopass` and without it? I understand from your answer that this follows from the wording of the standard but isn't that a loophole in the standard then? Consequently, is it safe to use the `nopass` version?

Comment: And thank you for the `elemental` procedure suggestion. This sounds as the cleanest solution if it works, I will try it.

Comment: Each element of an array must have the same dynamic and declared type, so that's not the problem.  For `pass`, if there's something like `call x%sub` for `x` and array, that can actually be resolved to an elemental binding.  However, for detailed specifics on reasoning for disallowing array passed objects: that's beyond me.  Compiler and standards people do frequent this site, or you may be better asking on comp.lang.fortran.

Comment: You can avoid writing an elemental subroutine for the assignment, but making the subroutine not type-bound.